# Generating nested attributes for FactoryGirl objects with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, nested-attributes

I'm using RSpec and Factory Girl to test my application. What I'm trying to do is the following: I have a object which accepts nested attributes, and it is not valid that nested attribute. I want to test that the POST works:

```
let(:valid_attributes) { build(:user).attributes }
it "creates a new User" do      
  expect {
    post :create, {user: valid_attributes}, valid_session
  }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

That's the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |x|
    name "Homer"
    after(:build) do
      build :address
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the hash returned by `build(:user).attributes` does not have the `address`, although if I inspect the object created by `build(:user)`, the `address` is correctly built.

Is there some way to easily generate a hash with the nested attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering myself to show a technically working solution:

```
let(:valid_attributes) {attributes_for(:user, address_attributes: attributes_for(:address))}
```

This works, but I find it quite clunky. In complex cases the code would get incredibly verbose and ugly. As I would expect something nicer, I'm not voting this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your object, while building it via parameters, so I'd solve your task this way:

```
let(:valid_attributes) { attributes_for(:user, address: attributes_for(:address)) }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick, the address is blank. Also, when you submit it, I guess address_attributes is expected rather than address as key. Also, if you have several nested attributes, it seems a lot of work :/